# Conda environment activation error: "The system cannot find the path specified." (windows 10)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, anaconda3

After installation of anaconda3, I launched jupyter notebook Using the Anaconda command prompt and it worked perfectly. Later on having already shut down my computer, upon start up I tried to open jupyter notebook via Anaconda command prompt and it opens another terminal with the following warning message.

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
```

`Warning: This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment please see https://conda.io/activation`

I went to https://conda.io/activation which gave me a command to run in Anaconda prompt

```
c:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate base
```

This command returned

```
C:\Users\Daniel>c:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate
```

`The system cannot find the path specified.`

I found a solution on https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#path-error
[Solution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6JnL.png)
but I don't know to to implement it.
I also tried getting the paths of python and conda from command prompt. conda's path is correct while '>where python' returned "INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)."

```
C:\Users\Daniel>where python
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)
```

Comment: Clearly `c:\Anaconda3\Scripts` is incorrect, but without access to your computer, we have no idea what the correct path is.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your account on that computer is "Daniel", so this is likely the command you need to run:

```
C:\Users\Daniel\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate base
```

Answer (score -1):

There could be some issue with your Anaconda PATH. You need to add Anaconda AND Anadconda scripts to your PATH enviroment variable. This can be done in the windows power shell, or the command prompt.

Simply enter `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Anaconda3;C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\` into the terminal and see if that works.

Comment: I just put this in command prompt and it did not work. I also tried getting the paths of python and conda from command prompt. conda's path is correct while  '>where python' returned "INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)."